# What can you say about a subgroup of $D_3$ that contains $R_{240}$ and a reflection $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

A subgroup satisfies the property that $(ab^{-1}) \in H$ for any $a,b \in H$. We can have $a=R_{240}$ and $b=R_{240}$. Then $ab^{-1}=e$. Thus the identity is in the subgroup $H$. We can continue by setting $a=R_{240}$ and $b=V$, then $ab^{-1}=D_{R}$. Thus $D_{R}\in H$. So, is the process of continuously setting $a$ and $b$ to elements $\in H$ and then getting $ab^{-1}$ $\in H$correct? Then eventually we would get $H=D_{3}$, right?

The Cayley Table found on the first page of the following link is helpful
http://homepages.ohiodominican.edu/~cottrilj/classes/mth450/ch01-answers.pdf

Comment: $R_{240{}{}{}}$?

Comment: Rotating 240 degrees

Comment: **degrees!** The horror! The horror! $\ddot\frown$

Comment: with a subgroup of order $3$ what does Lagrange tell you about $|H|$?

Comment: I haven't gotten to Lagrange yet

Comment: I would call it $D_6$ but the notation of the dihedral group is not always consistent between authors.  There is a subgroup of rotations i.e. $\{e, R, R^{-1}\}$  and subgroups for each reflection $\{e,V\}, \{e,D_L\},$ and $\{e,D_R\}$  But a subgroup with both a rotation and a reflection will generate the entire group.  I think that is what you say, just trying to be clear.

Comment: @Doug M is there a reason/theorem that explains why it generates the entire group? The only way I figured that out was by continuously computing $ab^{-1}$

Comment: If the property that $(ab^{-1}) \in H$ for all $ab\in H$ is an essential property of a group.  i.e. every in the group has an inverse element in the group, and the group is closed under addition.  So, it is a little bit odd to me that this would be spelled out.  Putting it together, $a\in H \implies a^{-1}, e \in H$  and $a,b \in H \implies ab, a^{-1}b \in H$ and that gives you all 6 elements.

Comment: The group $D_3$ only has six elements, and you've assuming that your subgroup contains elements of order $2$ and $3$. What are the possibilities?